# Using Python to extract info from an XML, output as a list

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to extract data from this XML document and have the output be a list:

ex:

```
['10-Yard Fight (USA, Europe)', '1942 (Japan, USA)', .......]
```

I can only figure out how to make it many independent lists.

ex:

```
['10-Yard Fight (USA, Europe)']
['1942 (Japan, USA)']
[.......]
```

XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
<header>
    <listname>Nintendo Entertainment System</listname>
    <id>003</id>
    <lastlistupdate>10/16/2014</lastlistupdate>
    <listversion>1.1 Final</listversion>
    <manufacturer>Nintendo</manufacturer>
    <media>
        <artwork></artwork>
        <video></video>
    </media>
    <exporterversion>HyperList XML Exporter Version 1.3 Copywrite (c) 2009-2011 William Strong</exporterversion>
</header>
<game name="10-Yard Fight (USA, Europe)" index="true" image="1" id="0034232">
    <description>10-Yard Fight (USA, Europe)</description>
    <cloneof></cloneof>
    <crc>3D564757</crc>
    <manufacturer>Nintendo</manufacturer>
    <year>1985</year>
    <genre>Football/Sports</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
</game>
<game name="1942 (Japan, USA)" index="" image="">
    <description>1942 (Japan, USA)</description>
    <cloneof></cloneof>
    <crc>171251E3</crc>
    <manufacturer>Capcom</manufacturer>
    <year>1986</year>
    <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
</game>
<game name="1943 - The Battle of Midway (USA)" index="" image="">
    <description>1943 - The Battle of Midway (USA)</description>
    <cloneof></cloneof>
    <crc>12C6D5C7</crc>
    <manufacturer>Capcom</manufacturer>
    <year>1988</year>
    <genre>Shoot-&apos;Em-Up</genre>
    <rating>HSRS - GA (General Audience)</rating>
    <enabled>Yes</enabled>
</game>
</menu>
```

My sample Python Code

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def databaseGameExtraction(xml):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
    games = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('game')
    for game in games:
        romKey = game.attributes['name']
        roms = [romKey.value]
        print(roms)
    return roms

databaseGameExtraction('Nintendo Entertainment System.xml')
```

also, I want to get the  value of 'Nintendo Entertainment System' to be returned as well.

In a perfect world the function would return the roms in list form and the system name in list form when called from another function.

Thanks,

- A very junior coder

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
roms = []

for game in games:
    romKey = game.attributes['name']
    roms.append(romKey.value)

print("all roms:", roms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the `roms` list iteratively from your XML:

```
roms = []
for game in games:
    rom_key = game.attributes['name']
    roms.append(rom_key.value)
```

or better written as a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
roms = [game.attributes['name'].value for game in games]
```

You can also extract “Nintendo Entertainment System” using:

```
xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('listname')[0].firstChild.data
```

that leaves us with:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def databaseGameExtraction(xml):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
    roms = [game.attributes['name'].value
            for game in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('game')]
    compagny = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('listname')[0].childNodes[0].data
    return roms, compagny

roms, compagny = databaseGameExtraction('Nintendo Entertainment System.xml')
print(compagny)
print(roms)
```

Comment: Thanks, this got part of it, I couldn't get the sample code of "list-comprehension working, but got the result I wanted.

Comment: @BenElder Woops. Forgot to use `.value` to extract the string out of the `minidom.Attr` object. Fixed now.